# jQuery unique function

Tags: jquery

The page over here http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.unique/  suggests "Sorts an array of DOM elements, in place, with the duplicates removed. Note that this only works on arrays of DOM elements, not strings or numbers."

However i was able to remove duplicates with numbers using $.unique..why does it say that it does not work on strings on numbers?

Answer (score 1):

It does work currently based on the implementation. I would guess the documentation is the way it is because `.unique` isn't actually in jQuery, [it's calling into the Sizzle engine](http://sizzlejs.com), specifically: `Sizzle.uniqueSort` ([see here for how it currently works](http://github.com/jeresig/sizzle/blob/master/sizzle.js#L140)).

Given that Sizzle can change how it implements this at any time, it's best to restrict the documentation to the cases that will always work, rather than include what might be a breaking change in the future.